# Filter array of objects while removing duplicates based on key pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working on a little coding project for my own enjoyment, and I'm stumped by a problem of sorts. I have working code for now, but I know it could be cleaned up. Essentially, I'm trying to take an array of objects, and only return unique elements that meet certain criteria.

With this example data:

```
[{
    "title": "1. Title of first song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001_r720P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 44043684,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": false,
    "frameWidth": 1280,
    "frameHeight": 720,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "1. Title of first song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001_r240P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 653534,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": false,
    "frameWidth": 320,
    "frameHeight": 240,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "2. Title of second song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002_r240P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 45456456,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": false,
    "frameWidth": 320,
    "frameHeight": 240,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "2. Title of second song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002_r720P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 3453453,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": true,
    "frameWidth": 1280,
    "frameHeight": 720,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "3. Title of third song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r240P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 45456456,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": false,
    "frameWidth": 320,
    "frameHeight": 240,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "3. Title of third song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r720P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 3453453,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": true,
    "frameWidth": 1280,
    "frameHeight": 720,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "3. Title of third song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r720P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 3453453,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": false,
    "frameWidth": 1280,
    "frameHeight": 720,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  },
  {
    "title": "3. Title of third song",
    "file": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r1080P.mp4",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"
    },
    "filesize": 15611561561,
    "trackImage": {
      "url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg",
      "modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"
    },
    "mimetype": "video/mp4",
    "subtitled": false,
    "frameWidth": 1920,
    "frameHeight": 1080,
    "duration": 233.29973333333334
  }
]
```

I would like to filter this down and return a somewhat trimmed-down version of the 1st, 4th and 7th elements. My criteria is the following:

- Discard elements with a frameHeight higher than a user-specified value (in this example, we'll assume that this value is 720)
- Only return unique (based on title) elements in final set
- Keep highest resolution items (based on frameHeight)
- Prefer non subtitled media if possible (ie, if both subtitled and non-subtitled element exist at the highest allowed resolution, keep only non-subtitled element)

In addition, I'd like the return array's objects to include only 4 keys: "title", "url" (which would be mapped from file.url), "filesize", and "duration"

I've tried various things so far, including:

- sorting the array based on each element's frameHeight in descending order, then
- looping over the sorted array and pushing values into a new array if title doesn't exist in array, then
- filtering out subtitled versions for each element, but only if a non-subtitled version is present at that item's resolution.

As you can tell, what I have so far is messy and very ... inelegant.

Here it is:

```
// data is my data, reverse sorted by frameHeight
function getMediaInfo(data) {
  let mediaFiles = [];
  for (var mediaFileItem of data) {
    if ((mediaFileItem.frameHeight !== 0 && mediaFileItem.frameHeight > prefs.maxRes) || mediaFiles.filter(mediaFile => {
        return mediaFile.title == mediaFileItem.title && mediaFile.subtitled == mediaFileItem.subtitled
      }).length > 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      mediaFiles.push({
        title: mediaFileItem.title,
        filesize: mediaFileItem.filesize,
        url: mediaFileItem.file.url,
        subtitled: mediaFileItem.subtitled,
        duration: mediaFileItem.duration
      });
    }
  }
  if (mediaFiles.length > 1) mediaFiles = mediaFiles.filter(mediaFile => !mediaFile.subtitled);
  return mediaFiles.reverse();
}
```

I would like to use some sort of combination of `filter`, `map` and `reduce`, but quite frankly I'm not sure where to start.

I'm not sure if one `reduce` could manage all that, or if I would need to chain a few things together. In any case, I'm looking for something clean and elegant, not a bunch of `for` loops like I have at the moment.

I'll appreciate any insight into how to best approach this. Right now like I said... I'm stumped.

Thank you all!

Comment: I would just make a reduce that filters out or in based on your criteria. It's easy enough to run checks along the way to determine if a title exists and if it does to compare frameheight etc. I think you need to show your attempt first to find the refinement you're seeking

Comment: I've added what I have so far, but like I said.. It's ugly as heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that performs the filtering, the grouping (using a `Map`), the retaining of the best scoring object per group, and the reduction to a few properties:

```js
function convert(data, maxFrameHeight=720) {
    data = data.filter(({frameHeight}) => frameHeight <= maxFrameHeight);
    let map = new Map(data.map(item => [item.title, item]));
    for (let item of data) {
        let {frameHeight, subtitled} = map.get(item.title);
        if ((item.frameHeight - frameHeight || subtitled - item.subtitled) > 0) {
            map.set(item.title, item);
        }
    }
    return Array.from(map.values(), ({title, file: {url}, filesize, duration}) =>
        ({title, url, filesize, duration})
    );
}

let data = [{"title": "1. Title of first song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001_r720P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 44043684,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": false,"frameWidth": 1280,"frameHeight": 720,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "1. Title of first song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001_r240P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 653534,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_001.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": false,"frameWidth": 320,"frameHeight": 240,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "2. Title of second song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002_r240P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 45456456,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": false,"frameWidth": 320,"frameHeight": 240,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "2. Title of second song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002_r720P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 3453453,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_002.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": true,"frameWidth": 1280,"frameHeight": 720,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "3. Title of third song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r240P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 45456456,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": false,"frameWidth": 320,"frameHeight": 240,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "3. Title of third song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r720P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 3453453,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": true,"frameWidth": 1280,"frameHeight": 720,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "3. Title of third song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r720P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 3453453,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": false,"frameWidth": 1280,"frameHeight": 720,"duration": 233.29973333333334},{"title": "3. Title of third song","file": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003_r1080P.mp4","modifiedDatetime": "2019-02-06 03:40:52"},"filesize": 15611561561,"trackImage": {"url": "https://mediafiles.abc/files/media_E_003.jpg","modifiedDatetime": "2021-03-15T12:34:06+00:00"},"mimetype": "video/mp4","subtitled": false,"frameWidth": 1920,"frameHeight": 1080,"duration": 233.29973333333334}];
let result = convert(data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Holy moly that was fast! Thank you so much. I wasn't expecting actual code that works, just a general nudge in the right direction. Thank you for your answer; I'll be reading up on Maps now, as I haven't used them in the past